# Kendo UI Icons not displayed in Web browser control

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, webbrowser-control

I have a website developed using Kendo UI(kendoui.professional.2017.1.118.commercial). The Kendo icons(Grid Edit(k-i-edit) and delete command button icons and calendar control icons and grid pager icons, etc.) are not visible when i open my website in Microsoft Browser Control where as if i open the website in Internet Explorer browser the icons are displayed.

Observed the following:
I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 OS where the IE Enhanced Security Configuration is "ON". If i make this "OFF", able to see the icons in the Web Browser control.

Is there any workaround to display the icons in Web browser control with out making IE Enhanced Security Configuration Off?